# How to determine which forms in a formset are valid and filled out?

Tags: django, django-forms

If you look at the [example here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#using-initial-data-with-a-formset),

```
>>> for form in formset:
...     print form.as_table()
<tr><th><label for="id_form-0-title">Title:</label></th><td><input type="text" name="form-0-title" value="Django is now open source" id="id_form-0-title" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_form-0-pub_date">Pub date:</label></th><td><input type="text" name="form-0-pub_date" value="2008-05-12" id="id_form-0-pub_date" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_form-1-title">Title:</label></th><td><input type="text" name="form-1-title" id="id_form-1-title" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_form-1-pub_date">Pub date:</label></th><td><input type="text" name="form-1-pub_date" id="id_form-1-pub_date" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_form-2-title">Title:</label></th><td><input type="text" name="form-2-title" id="id_form-2-title" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_form-2-pub_date">Pub date:</label></th><td><input type="text" name="form-2-pub_date" id="id_form-2-pub_date" /></td></tr>
```

You'll see the first form is filled out, the 2nd 2 aren't. I want to render that filled out form as hidden, and the other 2 as visible. How do I distinguish between the two?

I think `form.is_valid` will return true for blank forms in a formset, no?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to render the existing models at all if they are just going to be hidden?

Something like the following will just give you a set of empty forms, excluding any existing objects:

```
formset = MyFormset(queryset=MyModel.objects.none())
```

Comment: Yes, but why do you want them to be submitted at all if they aren't displayed to the user?

Comment: Hidden fields are used all the time on the web. They could be populated via JavaScript, or they can be used to propagate data to the next page... I want to keep the data there until they complete the *whole* form, and, in fact, they *are* displayed... just not as form fields. They're rendered as text, which can't be edited, only deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind... solution is actually pretty simple.

```
{{vehicle_formset.management_form}}
{% if vehicle_formset.initial_forms %}
    {% for vehicle_form in vehicle_formset.initial_forms %}
            {% for field in vehicle_form %}{{ field.as_hidden}}{% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% for vehicle_form in vehicle_formset.extra_forms %}
      <!-- render non-hidden forms -->
{% endfor %}
```